# React VX Chart: React does not recognize the `xScale` prop on a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React VX Chart. I have installed all the required packages. Code From VX Site: https://github.com/hshoff/vx

```
import React from 'react';
import { appleStock } from '@vx/mock-data';
import { Group } from '@vx/group';
import { scaleTime, scaleLinear } from '@vx/scale';
import { AreaClosed } from '@vx/shape';
import { AxisLeft, AxisBottom } from '@vx/axis';
import { LinearGradient } from '@vx/gradient';
import { extent, max } from 'd3-array';

const data = appleStock;

const width = 750;
const height = 400;

const x = d => new Date(d.date);
const y = d => d.close;

// Bounds
const margin = {
  top: 60,
  bottom: 60,
  left: 80,
  right: 80,
};
const xMax = width - margin.left - margin.right;
const yMax = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const xScale = scaleTime({
  range: [0, xMax],
  domain: extent(data, x)
});
const yScale = scaleLinear({
  range: [yMax, 0],
  domain: [0, max(data, y)],
});

export default () => (
  <div>
    <svg width={width} height={height}>
      <Group top={margin.top} left={margin.left}>
        <AreaClosed
          data={data}
          xScale={xScale}
          yScale={yScale}
          x={x}
          y={y}
          fill={"url(#gradient)"}
          stroke={""}
        />
      </Group>
    </svg>
  </div>
)
```

I tried to run this code but got this error. Let me know if I'm missing anything. Thanks in advance.
Error on console: React does not recognize the `xScale` prop on a DOM element.

Answer (score 6):

There were breaking changes introduced in v0.0.181. Instead of passing xScale as a prop, you scale the return value in the x accessor like so:

```
     <AreaClosed
        data={stock}
        x={d => xScale(xStock(d))}
        y={d => yScale(yStock(d))}
        yScale={yScale}
        strokeWidth={1}
        stroke={'url(#gradient)'}
        fill={'url(#gradient)'}
        curve={curveMonotoneX}
      />
```

For an up to date example please see: https://vx-demo.now.sh/areas

For an overview of all the breaking changes please see: https://github.com/hshoff/vx/pull/383

Hope that helps and thanks for checking out vx!